# OpenCV how to copy GpuMat to another GPU pointer and copy back to verify correctness?

Tags: opencv, cuda

Any body could give me a workable example?

I want copy a 3 channel image from GpuMat to another gpu pointer, and I want the pointer stores data exactly same as original image.

How to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV provides the function [`assignTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#a03e76eb8993215020cff624ace66d7e6) to copy an image, and also the [`clone`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d60/classcv_1_1cuda_1_1GpuMat.html#ae1d42819f7f3251478cd6edab8069758) function which is simpler in your case.

Alternatively, if you get any trouble with that, you could use the `ptr` function to get the raw pointer on the GPU device and then use the CUDA API (eg [`cudaMemcpy`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html)).

Comment: Sir, you just repeated my question, not answer my question. I want using cudaMemcpy copy a GpuMat to my another gpu location, but how???? I tried but failed, I need a workable example.

Comment: Well you just need to call `GpuMat copy = yourImage.clone();` and then call `copy.ptr()` to "copy a 3 channel image from GpuMat to another gpu pointer [...] exactly same as original image". This is straightforward and the documentation is pretty clear about that.

Comment: Can u give me a workable example? I tried a little bit but the data copied to gpu ptr is totally wrong.